# almost everything animates in ios5

Tags: ios5, uiviewanimation

I am working on an App built with Xcode 4.1 and linked against iOS 4.0. Today I have started testing on iOS5 to get it ready by the time the new OS launches.

We have an interesting issue where almost every UIView subclass animates when they are redrawn. The views returned as section headers of a table view are animated every time the user scrolls for instance. But practically almost any UIView update is animated. The effect on the screen is very disorienting.

I can't find anything on this issue. But I must be missing out on some big changes or doing something very wrong.

Anybody experiencing similar issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on what I've seen of iOS 5 this isn't normal behavior.

It sounds like you are wrapping some call to that TableView inside of a UIView animation block, so any call the UITableView makes (Such as LayoutSubviews) is also in that animation block. Another possibility is that you forgot to properly commit an animation, so all UIView changes past that are also included.

There have been some changes to UIView animations and the way they are run. Just anecdotally, I've had some trouble with Animations that used to run sequentially running on top of each other. So, maybe this is a bug in your code that was just never noticeable before.

Comment: Yes the reason was a forgotten [UIView commitAnimations] call. It never showed up in iOS4 but became visible in iOS5.